# bootstrap datepicker multidates getDates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I am using bootstzrap datepicker with multidates option on

when I use

```
.datepicker("getDates")
```

i get date in format "2014-10-13T22:00:00.000Z" which results in error when trying to insert this values into the same multidatepicker on page reload, since there I use format dd.mm.yyyy

the funciton i use to insert dates is

```
.datepicker("setDates",nbworkersDates[i][0])
```

where nbworkersDates[i][0] is an array of elements

the error I am getting is that all dates are set to today
any suggestions how to solve the problem?
thank you

this is my whole code to fill the row with data

```
for (var i in nbworkersDates) {
    var innerdata = (nbworkersDates[i]);
    $('.workerDatesrow').each(function(i,r){
        //console.log(nbworkersDates[i][0]);
        //$('.nbworkersDate',r).val(nbworkersDates[i][0]),
        $('.nbworkersDate',r).datepicker({
            multidate: true,
            format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            multidateSeparator: ','
                        }).datepicker('setUTCDates', nbworkersDates[i][0].map(function(x) {
                            console.log('datum '+ x);   
                            return new Date(x.substr(0, 10));
    }));
        $('.nbworkersDate', r).datepicker("setDates",nbworkersDates[i][0]),
        $('.nbworkersnumber',r).val(nbworkersDates[i][1]),
        $('.nbworkersfrom',r).val(nbworkersDates[i][2]),
        $('.nbworkersto',r).val(nbworkersDates[i][3]);
        });
```

and data in the json

```
 "nbworkersDates":[[["2014-10-13T22:00:00.000Z","2014-10-14T22:00:00.000Z","2014-10-15T22:00:00.000Z"],"","",""],[["2014-10-13T22:00:00.000Z","2014-10-20T22:00:00.000Z","2014-10-27T23:00:00.000Z"],"","",""]]
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert array of strings?

Comment: Yes, since setDates accepts array

Comment: I have written the answer for your question. Is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [bootstrap-datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js) internal method **parseDate** cannot parse your date strings. See at line 1541. The condition `parts.length === fparts.length` is not satisfied for your strings. For example, `'2014-10-14T00:00:00.000Z'` will be splited in `parts = ['2014', '10', '14T00', '00', '00', '000Z']`, when `format = 'yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z'` will be splited in `fparts = ['yyyy', 'mm', 'dd']`. Then the condition will be `6 === 3` and **parseDate** will return just current date.

Create new `Date` object before `'setDates'` (use `'setUTCDates'` instead), a time part should be zero. ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/27rznnLb/8/))

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-ddT22:12:34.000Z',
    multidateSeparator: ',   '
}).datepicker('setUTCDates', [
    '2014-10-14T22:00:00.000Z',
    '2014-10-15T22:14:00.000Z',
    '2014-10-16T22:20:00.798Z'
].map(function(x) {
    return new Date(x.substr(0, 10));
}));
```

Comment: found my bug and thanx for the solution